# I use while loop between two AND operator But i get syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

```
    select (SELECT count(distinct t.id)
FROM test As t, package AS p, packagetestassoc as pt, course AS c, student as s
WHERE p.id = pt.packageid AND find_in_set(t.id, pt.testid) <> 0 AND 
t.status = 1 AND find_in_set(c.id,p.courseid) AND 

WHILE (ctr < i) DO
    SET ctr = ctr + 1;
    SET tmp_str = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, ',',ctr), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,',',ctr-1))+1),',','');
    SELECT find_in_set(tmp_str, p.courseid);
END WHILE;

AND s.id = studentid1 AND 
(p.packagecost =0 or
p.id IN (SELECT ps.packageid FROM paymentstatus AS ps WHERE ps.studentid = studentid1))) AS totaltest,
```

In this procedure i get syntax error anybuddy help me to solve this problem???

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: probably you can't use while loop inside where statment

Comment: any alternative solution???

Comment: error #1064 at line 22.

Answer (score 0):

You have used ";" inside your query which is the culprit.

declare  tmp_str above the while loop & try the below part. Create a stored procedure. Inside this stored procedure, write like this:

```
WHILE (ctr < i) DO
    SET ctr = ctr + 1;
    SET tmp_str = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, ',',ctr),   
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,',',ctr-1))+1),',','');
    set cond = concat(cond, ' and find_in_set(tmp_str, p.courseid) ');
END WHILE;
```

Update your query:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("select (SELECT count(distinct t.id)
                  FROM test As t, package AS p, packagetestassoc as pt, course AS c, student as s
WHERE p.id = pt.packageid AND find_in_set(t.id, pt.testid) <> 0 AND 
t.status = 1 AND find_in_set(c.id,p.courseid) AND ",  cond ,"  

AND s.id = studentid1 AND 
(p.packagecost =0 or
p.id IN (SELECT ps.packageid FROM paymentstatus AS ps WHERE ps.studentid = studentid1))) AS totaltest,....";

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Not colon, you have used semi colon after the ' END WHILE'

Comment: Also use the while loop out side the query... what is the value of 'i'?

Comment: you can't use semicolon inside the select query

Comment: in every rotation of loop tmp_str change it's value for upper given code i will get only last value not alll values form loop..

Comment: Ok, got the point,I have updated my answers...but for that case you need to use prepare statement.I have added example for the same.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: As per the requirement, only asked to find out the source of error.